# Mock a repository while testing an api controller

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

Im trying to get familiar with using MOQ and mocking in general.  So I want to test an api controller which uses an assembly which serves as a repository for getting/updating data etc.
eg a structure like this.

```
HomeController
    Index
        Repository.GetSomeData  (returns JSON object)
```

This repository class has an interface, and that is what is injected via the .net core startup class. The method in this case, GetSomeData does a number of steps via calls to the Db, as well as reading a file from the file system, parsing it and moving it off to another folder.

Question:  How can a "mocked" Repository work without doing the things that the "real" object does?  All the examples I see are simple addition, returning strings etc.

Comment: Could you share source and interfaces of controller and repository?

Answer (score 0):

When you mock something like your repository, you going to stub out methods on the repository to return some canned result. Calls to those methods on the repository mock, then, bypass the real methods and instead just do what you've stubbed.

Essentially, you need to first identity what methods will be utilized. Then, you should determined appropriate responses those methods should return based on the particular scenario you're attempting to unit test. Then, you create the mock and add stubs for those methods with those responses.

The whole point of mocking is to remove variables, so you're intentionally trying to get to the "happy path": the set of internal responses that put the action in the state you need it to be in for specific test you're conducting.